# Is there a function i can use to get the equation for the trendline?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know I can get it on the graph by checking show equation but I was wondering if there's a formula that spits out the equation itself in a cell?

I need to do this for thousands of separate data sets and graphing them is just not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LINEST function calculates the statistics for a line by using the "least squares" method to calculate a straight line that best fits your data, and then returns an array that describes the line. (from Excel help)
Not sure, but you may need to enable the Analysis Toolpack addin before being able to use that function.

Comment: that's not exactly what i was looking for.  i was actually looking for the formula that describes the slope of the trendline, i.e y=4x+100.  seems like there should be a formula that takes cared of this, maybe i should rewrite my question.  thanks anyways good sir

Comment: But that is exactly what LINEST does, AFAIK.

Comment: hmmm i'm getting 1.0 as the answer.  maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: and i do have analyst pack turned on as well

Comment: RTFM ! You need to enter that function as an array formula to get all the parameters.

Comment: no i used the array function, i just had the x and y backwards, i also used the intercept function to get my Y intercept so I'm good now.  thanks for the help good sir