# Is there a formula that returns the equation for the Slope of the trendline?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a function i can use to get the equation for the trendline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615847/is-there-a-function-i-can-use-to-get-the-equation-for-the-trendline)

i know you can find it if you do a plot graph and enable trendline equation, i was wondering if there's a way i can use a formula to derive it.  i have thousands of data sets and graphing each one of those is just not an option.

Comment: Linear, i've tried Linest with analyst pack turned on but that just returns a value of 1 for me

Comment: @JamesChen You need to enter it as an array formula.  See Example 1 - slope and y intercept [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/linest-function-HP010342653.aspx)

Comment: Ok i got the slope, but it's not returning the Y-intercept.  or the B7=1 part.

Comment: Are you using VBA?  If so, [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=38677) looks promising.  See post #6 from Paul_Hossler about halfway down the page.

Comment: actually your formula plus the intercept formula works just fine.  but i will look into the VBA

hmmm how come i can only upvote your comment and not credit you with an answer?

Comment: Just added my comment as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `LINEST` function, however, you need to enter it as an array formula to get both the slope and y-intercept. See Example 1 - slope and y intercept [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/linest-function-HP010342653.aspx)